# Multiple git masters

Tags: git, replication

Two companies A and B both use git with central repositories to allow for project wikis, documentation, etc around their source code. Let's say they're both owned by a common parent organisation.

Users at both companies can push commits around to only other users within their own company, or to their central server.

Is it possible to extend this situation by opening a network route between the two central servers and having each project (based on a ruleset, perhaps as simple as a top level file called .exportable) replicated across both servers? Developers must be able to commit at each end, one can't simply be a mirror.

I suppose if it is possible, each master on accepting a commit would have to check the commit would go in, lock, reach out to the other master, lock, check it would commit and then from the far end commit and remove locks (this scenario would likely extend to more than two companies).

There are all sorts of problems I can envisage already; but is this possible, how, are there examples?

Edit: Perhaps projects could be name spaced and the masters could host their own projects and proxy to the other master for ones they don't own?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is possible to achieve exactly what you are describing, but for sure this will be quite complicated.

There is one simpler solution. Use ONE master server with git repository as a "master" and a second one as a "backup/slave". Slave could synchronize with master (you could use rsync or something). You have to in this scenario prohibit pushes to slave (pushes will be possibles only to master). This will provide two repositories with exactly the same content (as slave will periodically get changes from master)

In this case fetches (and of course pulls) will be possible from both master and slave. Also cloning repositories will be possible from both master and slave.

Before pushing (assuming that your origin repository is slave you will need to add second - master - repository with command git remote add).

So in a nutshell:

- you have master and slave repos you could pull, fetch, clone from
- both (save bandwidth, time as cloning and fetching is much often
  than pushing if there are many developers working on project) you can
- push only to master - this will eliminate complicated locks and sync 
  problems

Comment: One master is explicitly ruled out, unfortunately; company A users are not to access company b's master and vice versa, but both must be able to commit.

Comment: @rich You will need somehow add access from company A master to company B whatever master or slave. This will be needed at least for sync purposes.

Comment: Yes, but a one way sync to a slave at B wouldn't allow users there to commit changes back, as they can't access the master at A.

Comment: You can do separate development branches then (e.g. Amaster and Bmaster) and global master branch. People from company A are using Amaster, from B - Bmaster. From time to time (once a day) somebody merges changes from Amaster and Bmaster to master and resolve merge conflicts (if any). This could be probably some solution...

Answer (score 0):

Gitolite has support for this in what it calls "redirected pushes":

> Normally, a master, (and only a master), pushes to a slave, and the slaves are "read-only" to the users. Gitolite allows a slave to receive pushes from a user and transparently redirect them to the master.
>
> This simplifies things for users in complex setups, letting them use their local mirror for both fetch and push access to all repos.

http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/mirroring.html